# Reverse MemoryStream.ToArray()

Tags: c#, serialization, stream, binary, memorystream

I am getting an httpwebresponse stream (of a flash file), and I would like to save it as binary and later access that binary and display it as flash.  Right now, I am writing the response stream to a MemoryStream and then calling ToArray() on the MemoryStream.  I get a handy byte[].

How do I reverse that function?  How do I get the stream of the flash file from the byte[] I've generated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Super easy:

```
Stream s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx

Comment: haha just got that too.  I feel like an idiot for not seeing that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var s = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
```